# Why doesn't using a combination of display adapters work, such as Mini DP -> HDMI -> VGA?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, macbook, vga

I had two adapters with me, a Mini DP to HDMI and a HDMI to VGA adapter. I connected my Macbook Air's display out with the Mini DP to HDMI adapter, which was in turn connected to a HDMI to VGA adapter. Sure, I could buy a separate MiniDP to VGA adapter but I was wondering if this would work or not. It didn't.

Can someone shed light into why this combination does not work?

Comment: Was the HDMI to VGA adapter in question really a HDMI to VGA adapter or perhaps a VGA to HDMI adapter? Did you supply power to the adapter?

Comment: None of the adapters use a power supply. The adapter I have is HDMI (male) <-> VGA (female).

Comment: Because HDMI to/from DVI requires an active conversion, power is required. Sometimes, the power available on a regular connection isn’t enough. Can you perhaps identify the exact make and model of your HDMI-VGA converter?

Comment: @DanielB HDMI <-> DVI does not need active conversion. They both use TMDS. DP <-> HDMI/DVI does. However, DP source ports are often actually DP++, which have TMDS signal output as well.

Comment: @TomYan You’re right, of course. That was a typo of sorts, meant to write “HDMI to/from VGA”.

Answer (score 1):

VGA is analog port using basically 3 signals. When signal is converted between HDMI, DVI and VGA the same 4 contacts are used (see picture):
[image]

At the same time these signal are missing in Mini DP pure connector. http://pinouts.ru/Video/mini_displayport.shtml

So, additional circuit is required inside the adapter to convert signal levels from DP to VGA. Like this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#/media/File:DP_to_DVI_converter_unmounted.jpg

The chip on the board converts the voltage levels generated by the dual-mode DisplayPort device to be compatible with a DVI monitor. Another is required to convert signals to TTL VGA levels.

Comment: I’m sorry, but that’s not correct. Those are the DCC pins. They don’t carry image data but rather metadata about the display.

Comment: @ Daniel I know that CLK/SDA do not transfer the image data, RGB analog signals are used for that in VGA and TMDS data used for that in HDMI/DVI/DP. I meant that signaling levels are different because CLK/SDA pins are missing in DP, TMDS clock is used instead.

Comment: [They aren’t missing though.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Dual-mode) DDC is still used all the same. It is entirely (really!) unrelated to the actual image transmission.

Comment: VGA has 5 signals, not just three.  What's the purpose of showing a DVI connector, when it's not part of the question?  There's no usage of the *"same 4 contacts"* as you claim between VGA and HDMI; they're completely incompatible interfaces.  The conversion between such interfaces involves a lot more than the *"convert signal levels"* and/or *"voltage levels"*. that you allege.

Answer (score 0):

Where @Hardoman description is completely accurate, the shorter answer is simply that you can't magically convert analog signalling to digital.  VGA adapters typically only carry the existing analog signals to a display that supports analog inputs. (on the same cable that could do digital)  Display-port (and Mini-DP) are digital-only.  There is no Analog support.  So, you'll never find a passive VGA/Mini-DP adapter.  There are some active converters that will essentially take the analog signal, and process the data to produce a digital signal, but these generally are expensive, and only work for a limited set of resolutions/sync rates/etc...

Comment: The OP has an HDMI to VGA which, presumably has (read: it must have), an active DAC.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible issues.

Instead of *"adapters"*, you need to use *converters* (with active circuitry).
If either or both *"adapters"* are bogus adapters (passive devices consisting of wire and connectors), then the connection cannot work.

If the DP connection requires HDCP, and the HDMI-to-VGA converter is of the cheaper variety that doesn't support HDCP, then the connection won't work.

If the DP-to-HDMI converter and/or the HDMI-to-VGA converter do not have external power supplies, then the converters may be starved for power if they try to use line power, and connection won't work.

If you're using a display resolution that the HDMI-to-VGA converter does not support, then the connection won't work.  Usually only a subset of 480p, 1024x768, 720p, 1080i and 1080p is supported.

In theory it could work, but you have to use the proper converters and valid resolution.